# Marshal/Unmarshal int type

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I use an `int` type to represent an enum.  I want to convert it to string when I marshal it to JSON, AFAIK, I should implement `UnmarshalJSON` and `MarshalJSON`, but it complains:

> marshal error: json: error calling MarshalJSON for type
>   main.trxStatus: invalid character 'b' looking for beginning of
>   valueunexpected end of JSON input

when marshalling. Then I've add the quotes to the marshalled string:

```
func (s trxStatus) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte("\"" + s.String() + "\""), nil
}
```

the `Marshal` works now but it can't `Unmarshal` from the marshalled byte stream correctly.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type trxStatus int

type test struct {
    S trxStatus
    A string
}

const (
    buySubmitted trxStatus = iota
    buyFilled
    sellSubmiited
    sellFilled
    finished
)

var ss = [...]string{"buySubmitted", "buyFilled", "sellSubmiited", "sellFilled", "Finished"}

func (s *trxStatus) UnmarshalJSON(bytes []byte) error {
    status := string(bytes)
    // unknown
    for i, v := range ss {
        if v == status {
            tttt := trxStatus(i)
            *s = tttt
            break
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func (s trxStatus) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(s.String()), nil
}

func (s trxStatus) String() string {

    if s < buySubmitted || s > finished {
        return "Unknown"
    }

    return ss[s]
}

func main() {
    s := test{S: buyFilled, A: "hello"}
    j, err := json.Marshal(s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("marshal error: %v", err)
    }
    var tt test
    fmt.Println(json.Unmarshal(j, &tt))
    fmt.Println(tt)
}
```

Comment: 1. check error of json.Marshal, 2. export test's Field, else marshaling won't work. 3. Your MarshalJSON does not return json strings, i.e. missing quotes. 4. [woking example](https://play.golang.org/p/ROjER5DhsjI)

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks for the tip, see my edit.

Comment: it's the missing quotes mentioned in the updated comment.

Comment: I've add the the quotes, but the Unmarshal doesn't work

Comment: You're right the quotes need to be handled in both cases, Unmarshal as well. The `bytes` value is `"buyFilled"` not `buyFilled` matching simply against `v` will return false. updated example https://play.golang.org/p/KOZ37cgaYbj (an ugly way of handling the quotes i must say, you can do better than me if you put some thougth in it)

Comment: @mkopriva got it! Thanks. You should write it as an answer and I'll accept it gladly!

Comment: Note that building JSON strings manually is risky in general because escaping is tricky. A more robust implementation of MarshalJSON would `return json.Marshal(s.String())`.

Comment: Indeed. I'll let `json.Marshal` and `json.Unmarshal` do the tricky work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing your custom Marshaler and Unmarshaler implementations make sure to include or trim the surrounding double quotes of json strings.

```
func (s *trxStatus) UnmarshalJSON(bytes []byte) error {
    status := string(bytes)
    if n := len(status); n > 1 && status[0] == '"' && status[n-1] == '"' {
        status = status[1:n-1] // trim surrounding quotes
    }
    // unknown
    for i, v := range ss {
        if v == status {
            tttt := trxStatus(i)
            *s = tttt
            break
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func (s trxStatus) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(`"` + s.String() + `"`), nil
}
```